# Atags are non-sensical when booting custom RaspberryPi kernel

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, bare-metal, armv6

I'm working on a kernel for a RaspberryPi 1B+ and I'm having some trouble with the [ATAGS](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0013/d/Boot-Code/Booting-Linux/Kernel-parameters-using-ATAGs). My orientation for the implementation was [this page](http://www.simtec.co.uk/products/SWLINUX/files/booting_article.html#appendix_tag_reference).

The implementation for parsing looks something like this:

```c
typedef struct atag_header
{
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t tag_type;
} atag_header;


typedef struct atag_core
{
    uint32_t flags;
    uint32_t pagesize;
    uint32_t rootdevice;
} atag_core;

typedef struct atag_mem
{
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t address;
} atag_mem;

/* etc... */

typedef struct atag_t {
    atag_header header;
    union {
        atag_core core;
        atag_mem mem;
        atag_ramdisk ramdisk; 
        atag_initrd2 initrd2;
        atag_serial serial;
        atag_revision revision;
        atag_videolfb videolfb;
        atag_cmdline cmdline;
    };
} atag_t;

#define tag_next(t)     ((atag_t *)((uint32_t *)(t) + (t)->header.size))
#define tag_size(type)  ((sizeof(atag_header) + sizeof(type)) >> 2)
```

Now as far as I understand the atag's are passed to the kernel over `r2`, i.e.

```c
void kernel(uint32_t r0, uint32_t r1, uint32_t r2)
```

Now `r2` is supposed to be the address at which the list of ATAG's starts. I would like to get the RAM size, so I wrote a little function

```c
uint32_t get_mem_size(atag_t * atags) {
   while (atags->header.tag_type != ATAG_NONE) {
       if (atags->header.tag_type == ATAG_MEM) {
           return atags->mem.size;
       }
       atags = tag_next(atags);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

but this just returns zero (calling it with `get_mem_size((atag_t *)r2)`). So, I assumed that I was doing something wrong... Turns out, `r2` is always `0x6E750000` and well this is no `atag` so of course `tag_next` will never reach the memory segment..

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. Did I misunderstand something about these atags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying out I got it to work, but I still don't fully understand what the original problem was.

The way how I got my custom kernel onto the Pi worked something like this:

1. Use the RaspberryPi imager tool to flash Raspian onto a SD card.
2. Replace `kernel.img` with custom kernel.

Now most of the files on the SD card are actually not necessary when you are writing your custom kernel, in fact, you only need `bootcode.bin, start.elf, fixup.dat` and your kernel image. Once I had removed everything the ATAG address switched from `0x6E750000` to `0`. After some digging I found this [github repo](https://github.com/jncronin/rpi-boot/blob/c660254a663e2d0ace9baaceb90e0c259fe943ed/main.c#L168) with the following at the beginning of the `kernel_main`

```c
// Hack for newer firmware - assume if atags not specified then they are at 0x100
// We also check the zero address in case this is true - see later
if(atags == 0x0)
    atags = 0x100;
```

After adding this to my `kernel_main`, the code started working. So it seems my atags are not specified... Not sure why this happens or where exactly I would need to set this up, but this does the trick for now. If anyone knows what is going on here, please feel free to add to this/make your own answer.